# Call TypeScript Method from jquery in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, typescript2.0

Im using [boostrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) Dropdown in angular 2 forms with jquery. Onchange jquery event i want to call a Typescript onDropDownChangeChange method. But its not working.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
declare var $: JQueryStatic;

export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedValue: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {

        $(function() {
         var self = this;
          $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
            var selectedds = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
            self.onDropDownChangeChange(selectedds); //This is not working
            //this.onChange();
          });

        });  

  }

  onDropDownChangeChange(value: string) {
        this.selectedValue = value;
        this.PopulateGrid(selectedValue);
   }


}
```

Comment: what is the point in using jQuery to listen to that event while you can still use ngModel and/or template syntax to achieve this ?

Comment: General rule - every time you get tempted to use jQuery in an Angular/React/Vue app, there's a 99.999% chance there's a better way of doing things.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are confusing the scopes. It should be like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    var self = this;
    $(function() {

          $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){

              var selectedds = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
              self.onDropDownChangeChange(selectedds); //This is not working
              //this.onChange();

           }); 

    }); 
}
```

Comment: Ya its working fine now. onDropDownChange event Im populating Grid based on dropdown value. code is executing without any error, But Grid is not loading. Can you please help on this?

Comment: @PrabhuArumugam I don't know about Grids, I'm sorry : / you can ask another question about that if this one is resolved tho.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the context.

And to handle 3rd party library custom event, in some case you need tell Angular run your code after received the event like this.

```
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}
ngOnInit(): void {
    var self = this;
    this.zone.run(() => {
      $('.selectpicker').on('change', function(){
        var selectedds = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        self.onDropDownChangeChange(selectedds);
        //this.onChange();
      }); 
    });

  }
```